# What is a more efficient way to fill Columns based off values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, time-complexity

Lets say I have a dataframe column 'code' consisting of strings that reference data in a dictionary like so:

```
lst = ['a','b','c']*10000

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'code':lst
})

ref = {
    'a':{
        'LONG':1,
        'LAT':1,
        'COUNTRY':1
    },
    'b':{
        'LONG':2,
        'LAT':2,
        'COUNTRY':2
    },
    'c':{
        'LONG':3,
        'LAT':3,
        'COUNTRY':3
    }
}
```

I want to create 3 new dataframe columns, 'Long', 'Lat' and 'Country', and fill these columns based off the values their code references in the ref dictionary.

My current implementation is as follows:

```
df = df.reindex(columns = df.columns.tolist() + ['Country','Long','Lat'])

start_time = time.time()
for index in df.index:
    df.iloc[index,df.columns.get_loc('Country')]= ref[df.iloc[index,df.columns.get_loc('code')]]['COUNTRY']
    df.iloc[index,df.columns.get_loc('Long')]= ref[df.iloc[index,df.columns.get_loc('code')]]['LONG']
    df.iloc[index,df.columns.get_loc('Lat')]= ref[df.iloc[index,df.columns.get_loc('code')]]['LAT']

print("Time taken to run:  %s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

However this seems extremely inefficient and takes around 40 seconds to run on this dummy dataset with only 30000 entries. My actual dataset contains up to 2 million rows and did not even complete overnight. Any advice would be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: create a datframe from `ref` and then append two dataframes

Comment: your issue is that your working at an index level no matter the performance boost it will take a long time. even if we sped up your current approach from 10s per row to 0.2 s per row, that's still 0.2 * 2mil. try `df.join(pd.json_normalize(df['code'].map(ref)))`

Answer (score 0):

it could be like this

```py
df[['LONG', 'LAT', 'COUNTRY']] = pd.DataFrame(list(df["code"].map(ref)), index=df.index)
```

Comment: welcome, but I think the best is df[['LONG', 'LAT', 'COUNTRY']] = 
 pd.json_normalize(df['code'].map(ref)) which by Manakin